# Upload Excel using web.py

Tags: python, excel, file-upload, web.py

I have tried the following code by slightly modifying the example in [documentation](http://webpy.org/cookbook/fileupload)

```
class Upload():
  def POST(self):
    web.header('enctype','multipart/form-data')
    print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime())
    x = web.input(file={})
    filedir = '/DiginUploads' # change this to the directory you want to store the file in.
    if 'file' in x: # to check if the file-object is created
        filepath=x.file.filename.replace('\\','/') # replaces the windows-style slashes with linux ones.
        filename=filepath.split('/')[-1] # splits the and chooses the last part (the filename with extension)
        fout = open(filedir +'/'+ filename,'w') # creates the file where the uploaded file should be stored
        fout.write(x.file.file.read()) # writes the uploaded file to the newly created file.
        fout.close() # closes the file, upload complete.
```

But this works only for csv and txt documents. For Excel/pdf etc file gets created but it can't be opened (corrupted). What should I do to handle this scenario?

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21562204/uploading-encoding-xls-file-python-web-py) but it is about printing the content which does not address my matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `wb` (binary) mode when opening the file:

```
fout = open(filedir +'/'+ filename, 'wb')
```

Comment: Thanks it worked.. will you be able to explain further?

Comment: @MarlonAbeykoon if you would use the `w`, on windows, you would get corrupted files when writing the uploaded content since the end-of-line characters are handled differently, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665866/what-is-the-wb-mean-in-this-code-using-python. Hope that helps.